# ssh: "Access denied by PAM account configuration" for one non-root user but not another

Tags: ssh, remote-access, pam

On a VM I am initializing I am able to log in as one non-root user (`admin`) but not another (`tbbscraper`) over SSH with public key authentication.  The only error message I can find in any log file is

```
Sep 18 17:21:04 [REDACTED] sshd[18942]: fatal: Access denied for user tbbscraper by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

On the client side, the syndrome is

```
$ ssh -v -i [REDACTED] tbbscraper@[REDACTED]
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: [REDACTED]
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: [REDACTED]
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
Connection closed by [REDACTED]
```

Changing 'tbbscraper' to 'admin' allows a successful login: `debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).` appears instead of the "Connection closed" message.

This doesn't seem to be a permissions problem...

```
# for x in admin tbbscraper
> do ls -adl /home/$x /home/$x/.ssh /home/$x/.ssh/authorized_keys
> done
drwxr-xr-x 3 admin admin 4096 Sep 18 17:19 /home/admin
drwx------ 2 admin admin 4096 Sep 18 16:53 /home/admin/.ssh
-rw------- 1 admin admin  398 Sep 18 17:19 /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
drwxr-xr-x 3 tbbscraper tbbscraper 4096 Sep 18 17:18 /home/tbbscraper
drwx------ 2 tbbscraper tbbscraper 4096 Sep 18 17:18 /home/tbbscraper/.ssh
-rw------- 1 tbbscraper tbbscraper  398 Sep 18 17:18 /home/tbbscraper/.ssh/authorized_keys

# cmp /home/{admin,tbbscraper}/.ssh/authorized_keys ; echo $?
0
```

... nor a PAM-level access control problem ...

```
# egrep -v '^(#|$)' /etc/security/*.conf
#
```

... so none of the existing answers to similar questions would seem to apply.  The only other piece of evidence I've got is:

```
root@[REDACTED] # su - admin
admin@[REDACTED] $
```

but

```
root@[REDACTED] # su - tbbscraper
su: Authentication failure
(Ignored)
tbbscraper@[REDACTED] $
```

which suggests some larger-scale PAM issue, but I can't find anything obviously wrong with the stuff in `/etc/pam.d`.  Any ideas?

The VM is an EC2 instance, OS is Debian 7.1 (Amazon's off-the-shelf AMI).

Comment: `/etc/pam.d/sshd` please

Comment: @GioMac Never mind, I found the problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After all that, it turns out to have been a one-character typo in `/etc/shadow`.  Spot the difference:

```
admin:!:15891:0:99999:7:::
tbbscraper:!::15966:0:99999:7:::
```

That's right, there are two colons after the exclamation point on the `tbbscraper` line.  That shoves all the fields over one and makes PAM think that the account expired on January 8, 1970.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  This was useful for me: I'd manually created a user entry in /etc/passwd and forgotten to add a corresponding /etc/shadow entry.

Comment: @spazm Thanks for commenting.  This was useful for me: I'd manually copied users from another machine and forgotten to copy the /etc/shadow entry of the one user without a password.

Answer (score 11):

Thank you for posting your question. I was getting the same error, but my problem wasn't related to the shadow file. I found my fix and wanted to post an answer as well for anyone else Googling this error. This serverfault question comes up first.

Try checking the `/etc/security/access.conf` !

We're using Active Directory for authentication, but I needed to login in as a local, non-AD user (jenkins). My boss had originally setup the box with these line in the `/etc/security/access.conf`:

```
+:root:ALL
-:ALL:ALL
```

I changed it to the following and logins now work; I didn't even need to restart any services.

```
+:jenkins:ALL
+:root:ALL
-:ALL:ALL
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was renaming local CentOS 6 users, and forgot to rename them in /etc/shadow (who are password-less key-authenticated, didn't pop up in my mind), so the records for the new usernames were just absent in /etc/shadow. In /var/log/secure it was giving me unix_chkpwd error and Access denied by PAM:

```
    unix_chkpwd[12345]: could not obtain user info (user2)
    sshd[12354]: fatal: Access denied for user user2 by PAM account configuration
```

Comment: usermod(8) is your friend next time ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Had the same error message. 
Shutted down the sshd and restarted it in debug mode

```
    /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

this indicated the reason:

```
    debug3: User autossh not allowed because account is locked
            ...
    input_userauth_request: invalid user <username> [preauth]
```

Checked account:

```
    passwd -S <username>
```

which showed that the account was locked (flag "L")
Un-locked the account by setting a new password:

```
    passwd <username>
```

Done.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem this morning but the server authenticates users against Active Directory.  Turns out the user's domain password had expired.

Comment: Same phenomenon, different source of user account information :-)  It's possible that I should have filed a bug against ssh and/or PAM two years ago, asking for clearer logging of *why* a login attempt was denied; there is a security argument for not telling the person who *made* the attempt why it failed, but that wouldn't apply to system logs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and none of suggested options worked.  But I found in one of forums (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1960510) a "workaround" which worked perfectly.

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set

```
UsePAM no
```

While it's probably not the real solution, because something is definitely wrong with my machine (yesterday it was working fine!), this one at least works.

Comment: That worked for me, inherited a few machines where some had that issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was junk hitting ''/etc/tcb/USER/shadow'' after ext4 rootfs corruption in "interesting" conditions; it looked pretty texty so wasn't spotted during initial examination (can't reinstall the node right now but will have to).